# How expensive is it to call a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I've had a fairly good search on google and nothing has popped up to answer my question. As I know very little about web services (only started using them, not building them in the last couple of months) I was wondering whether I should be ok to call a particular web service as frequently as I wish (within reason), or should I build up requests to do in one go.

To give you an example, my app is designed to make job updates, which for certain types of updates will call the web service. It seems like my options are that I could create a datatable in my app of updates that require the web service and pass the whole datatable to the web service and then write a method in the web service to process the datatable's updates. Alternatively I could iterate through my entire table of updates (which includes other updates than those requiring the web service) and call the web service as when an update requires it.

At the moment it seems like it would be simpler for me to pass each update rather than a datatable to the web service.

In terms of data being passed to the web service each update would contain a small amount of data (3 strings, max 120 characters in length). In terms of numbers of updates there would probably be no more than 200.

Comment: I'm wondering, why didn't I never thought this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering whether I should be ok to call a particular web service as frequently as I wish (within reason), or should I build up requests to do in one go.

Web services or not, any calls routed over the network would benefit from building up multiple requests, so that they could be processed in a single round-trip. In your case, building an object representing all the updates is going to be a clear winner, especially in setups with slower connections.

When you make a call over the network, these things need to happen when a client communicates to a server (again, web services or not):

1. The data associated with your call gets serialized on the client
2. Serialized data is sent to the server
3. Server deserializes the data
4. Server processes the data, producing a response
5. Server serializes the response
6. Server sends serialized response back to the client
7. The response is deserialized on the client

Steps 2 and 6 usually cause a delay due to network latency. For simple operations, latency often dominates the timing of the call.

The latency on fastest networks used for high-frequency trading is in microseconds; on regular ones it is in milliseconds. If you are sending 100 packages one by one on a network with 1ms lag (2ms per roundtrip), you are wasting 200ms just on the network latency! This one fifth of a second, a lot of time by the standards of today's CPUs. If you can eliminate it simply by restructuring your requests, it's a great reason to do it.

Comment: I suspected this would be the case. I just wondered whether web services specifically have a large performance hit. The other updates are done on another database where I simply call a stored procedure and pass in each update (don't have control over the stored procedure) and this doesn't take very long. I was wondering how this would compare against calling the web service each time.

Comment: @sr28 Web services do not come with a huge performance penalty attached on top of your regular distributed calls. By the way, since you are talking about stored procedures, the analogy here is very handy: some stored procedures are created for a single purpose of avoiding multiple roundtrips to the RDBMS server - essentially, for the same reason why you bundle web service calls, even though your RDBMS is very often located on the same local network as your app server. The small increase in complexity associated with bundling requests pays off with significant improvements in the performance.

Comment: That's handy to know that web services don't come with a huge performance penalty. However, as per your suggestion I've proceeded down the datatable route, which may be a little more complex for me in terms of recording update success / failure but you have convinced me of its benefits.

Answer (score 1):

You should usually favor coarse-grained remote interfaces over a fine-grained ones.

Consider adding a 10ms network latency to each call - what would be the delay for 100 updates?